# How do I pass a string array to another form

Tags: c#, arrays

I have read several articles on this site.  I'm still very confused about exactly how to do it.

I have a String array with 10 strings.  I want to do one of two things:

1. Either pass the string to a struct or class then retrieve them on the next form.

   or
2. I need to pass the string array directly into the next form.

I keep getting error--very confused about how to pass the string array.  Guys I have tried every way I can possibly think of.
Please help.

Comment: What language are you talking about? What's a "form"?

Comment: Im sorry I forgot to mention c#

Comment: And what kind of error do you get? can you place the error here?

Comment: Show what you have tried please

Comment: I have tried setting up a getter and setter in a separate class.  Then it says I need some sort of object identifier.  (not real sure what that is)

Comment: I just need to pass a string array list to another form.  Here I have been fighting with my program for about the last 3 hours...now Im fighting with this site to allow me to post my code

Answer (score 0):

Let's call the first form `Form1` and the second one `Form2` to keep things simple. Next, let's assume the constructors for those forms (in the code-behind) look like this *currently:*

```
public Form1() { ... }

public Form2() { ... }
```

Now, while running in an *instance* of `Form1` you need to launch `Form2` and get that array to the second form. Let's assume that the array is named `_vals` and it's a `private` `field` in the `Form1` class, so you can get to it.

Alright, we're almost there. But first we need to build a new constructor on `Form2` to *receive* this `string[]`:

```
public Form2(string[] vals) { ... }
```

and next, before we *finish*, we need to house that parameter in `Form2` somewhere:

```
private string[] _vals;
```

and then finally, in the *constructor*, we need to set that `field`; so back to the *new constructor* we just built:

```
public Form2(string[] vals)
{
    _vals = vals;
}
```

Alright, we are just about there, just one more step. When we launch `Form2`, we need to use the *new constructor:*

```
var f2 = new Form2(_vals);
f2.Show();
```

There you have it! Now you can pass the local `string[]` that exists on `Form1` to `Form2` via the *new constructor* you built on `Form2`.